# Windows 7 System Image Recovery: netsh error "The interface is unknown"

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, system-recovery

Trying to recover a Windows System Image from a Network Drive on a NAS.

1. I clicked System Image Recovery tool from the Windows 7 System recovery Options dialog on startup.
2. The Selected "Select a system image" -> Advanced -> Search for a system image on the network.
3. Said "yes" to Connect to the network, got no errors.
4. However on entering the network folder, `\\\server\share1\…` Recovery did not find any folder.
5. Using the "Command Prompt" option ran `netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.19 255.255.255 192.168.1.1` and got an error "The interface is unknown".
6. Interface is fine as I can list it using `ipconfig /all` or `netsh interface ip show config`.

Since The network IP address is not setup, I can see why the recovery tool never is able to browse to my network share.

I did try executing `wpeinit` first as some users have reported success with `netsh` after `wpeinit`. But no dice on my Windows 7 box.

Any clues on how to get the network connected to from Windows 7 Recovery options?

Comment: wpeinit is useful. It made the dhcp work for the interface on my system. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Before you run the netsh command, run `wpeinit`.
Example:

```
X:\windows\system\wpeinit
X:\windows\system\netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.19 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
```

This assumes your mask is `/24` and default gateway is `.254`, change as necessary.

Comment: This is a good answer, but more of an explanation about what the commands do would be nice.